# how to stop user use more than two fingers to touch

Tags: iphone, ipad

in my app, I want users only use one finger to touch the ipad, it means, when you touch the screen, others touches won't respond events......

any helps?

Comment: On this site users are usually wanted to repeat their questions just once...

Comment: @Vladimir what do you mean? What do you mean? :-)

Answer (score 2):

try disabling multitouch throug IB or through code.

Answer (score -1):

keep a track of count of touch, and then implement it accordingly.